# how to solve errors arising from the container when creating a GUI using Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUIWindow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame` theGUI = new JFrame();
           theGUI.setTitle("Visual studio code");
            theGUI .setSize(300,200);
            theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           JPanel northpanel  =new JPanel();
             northpanel .setBackground(Color.red);
           JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();
        eastPanel .setBackground(Color.blue);
        JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();
        westPanel .setBackground(Color.blue);
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel .setBackground(Color.red);
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel .setBackground(Color.green);
        container pane =GUI.getContentPane();
        pane.add(northpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pane.add(eastPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
        pane.add(westPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
        pane.add(southPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pane.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        theGUI.setVisible(true);

    } 
    
}

[{
    "resource": "/home/linc/Javaprojects/GUIWindow.java",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#3",
    "code": "570425394",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "GUI cannot be resolved",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 23,
    "startColumn": 25,
    "endLineNumber": 23,
    "endColumn": 28
},{
    "resource": "/home/linc/Javaprojects/GUIWindow.java",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#3",
    "code": "67108964",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The method add(JPanel, String) is undefined for the type container",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 24,
    "startColumn": 14,
    "endLineNumber": 24,
    "endColumn": 17
},{
    "resource": "/home/linc/Javaprojects/GUIWindow.java",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#3",
    "code": "67108964",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The method add(JPanel, String) is undefined for the type container",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 25,
    "startColumn": 14,
    "endLineNumber": 25,
    "endColumn": 17
},{
    "resource": "/home/linc/Javaprojects/GUIWindow.java",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#3",
    "code": "67108964",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The method add(JPanel, String) is undefined for the type container",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 26,
    "startColumn": 14,
    "endLineNumber": 26,
    "endColumn": 17
},{
    "resource": "/home/linc/Javaprojects/GUIWindow.java",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#3",
    "code": "67108964",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The method add(JPanel, String) is undefined for the type container",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 27,
    "startColumn": 14,
    "endLineNumber": 27,
    "endColumn": 17
},{
    "resource": "/home/linc/Javaprojects/GUIWindow.java",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#3",
    "code": "67108964",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The method add(JPanel, String) is undefined for the type container",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 28,
    "startColumn": 14,
    "endLineNumber": 28,
    "endColumn": 17

}]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you please format your question with a bit more care? You should separate the error messages from the actual code.

Also you should format your code with more care, the compiler is picky! Especially the row `container pane =GUI.getContentPane();` just cannot work: there is no class `container`,  probably you meant `Container`?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

I modified your code to create the following GUI.

[image]

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I separated the creation of the `JFrame` and the `JPanels`.  You size each of the `JPanels`, ideally by filling each JPanel with Swing components.  You pack the `JFrame`, letting it take the size of the `JPanels`.  Pay close attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GUIWindow implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GUIWindow());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame theGUI = new JFrame();
        theGUI.setTitle("Visual studio code");
        theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        theGUI.add(createPanel(Color.red), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        theGUI.add(createPanel(Color.blue), BorderLayout.EAST);
        theGUI.add(createPanel(Color.blue), BorderLayout.WEST);
        theGUI.add(createPanel(Color.red), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        theGUI.add(createPanel(Color.green), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        theGUI.pack();
        theGUI.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        theGUI.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createPanel(Color color) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(color);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        
        return panel;
    }

}
```